# What value bounds an ellipse of a bivariate population at one standard deviation?

Tags: r, bivariate

I am trying to draw an ellipse that bounds a bivariate distribution by the shared 1 sigma in 2D space (i.e. points that fall within one standard deviation of both populations). The function in R I am using takes the mean of both populations, the covariance matrix, and a parameter alpha, which is the probability of points falling outside of the ellipse (i.e. a value of 0.05 means 95% of all points are within).

My question: to bound the ellipse at one standard deviation, what is the value of alpha I should use? By trial and error I get ~ 1-0.39, but I would have thought it would be something like 1-0.6827*0.6827. What is this number exactly, and where does it come from?

```r
library(mixtools)

xs  <- rnorm(n=1e3, mean=1, sd=1)
ys  <- xs*2 + rnorm(n=1e3, mean=0, sd=2)
dat <- cbind(xs, ys)

layout(mat=matrix(1))
par(mar=c(5,5,1,1))
plot(xs, ys, xlim=c(-5,6), ylim=c(-10,15))
mixtools::ellipse(mu=colMeans(dat), sigma=cov(dat), alpha =1 - 0.39, 
    npoints = 300, col="green", lwd=3) 
points(x=mean(xs), y=mean(ys), pch=16, col="green", cex=1)
abline(h=mean(ys)+sd(ys), col="green")
abline(h=mean(ys)-sd(ys), col="green")
abline(v=mean(xs)+sd(xs), col="green")
abline(v=mean(xs)-sd(xs), col="green")
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: The area within 1 sd of the mean of X and also within 1 sd of the mean of Y is a rectangle, not an ellipse.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "one standard deviation of both populations"?

Comment: I mean points which fall within 1 standard deviation of x and one standard deviation of y--both the x and y value are within the 1 sigma envelope of both variables. When I plot this as bounded by a square, as Matt F. suggested, two of the corners of the squares hold no points. Since the general shape of the data is an ellipse, I thought that the shape that described the joint probability of a point falling with in one sigma of the mean of both x and y would not be square, but ellipsoid.

Comment: That's truly strange, because you start out by describing a rectangle and then tell us you're hoping it's an ellipse.  That's why I asked for clarification: *what is it you really want to determine?*

Comment: I want to know what value of alpha would create an ellipse whose edges touch a box bounded by +/- one standard deviation of x and +/- one standard deviation of y, and where this value comes from. From trial and error I found it was about 1-0.39=0.61, but I don't know the exact value or where it comes from. This value is not specific to this dataset, so there is some basic relation between alpha (a confidence interval) and the standard deviations, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: That's clear now -- but the answer depends on the specific bivariate distribution.  If you need a more definite answer than that, then you need to tell us what distribution you are interested in.  Bivariate Normal, perhaps?  If your question is only about the point data, then all you can do is count the points falling within that ellipse.

Comment: Yes, bivariate normal, both populations are normally distributed.

Comment: Please add clarifications from comments as an edit to the post! We want posts to be self-contained, and few people will see the comments